# How to use SVG polygon to create triangle?

Tags: html, svg, polygon, clip-path

I am trying to use SVG polygon to create a bottom triangle like shown in the below image:

[image]

So far, I have done this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="150px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <svg width="100%" x="0">
      <polygon points="0 0,50 50,100 0,100 100,0 100" fill="#424963"></polygon>
  </svg>
  <svg height="200px" width="50%" x="50%">
      <polygon points="0 50,100 0,100 100,0 100" fill="#ED0F0C"></polygon>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

I am unable to get that red triangle positioned properly. Can someone guide me through this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference to the spec read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon)

You're on the right path, adjusting the values of the polygon points will get you to where you need to be.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="250px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="#2f3753"/>
  <svg width="100%" x="0">
      <polygon points="0 25,50 50,100 25,100 50,0 50" fill="#424963"></polygon>
  </svg>
  <svg height="200px" width="50%" x="50%">
      <polygon points="0, 50, 220, -50, 60, 0" fill="#ED0F0C"></polygon>

  </svg>
</svg>
```

You'll also notice I've added in the rect to set the SVG background. Removing this or changing the fill will remove/change the background.

Comment: See my codepen [here](https://codepen.io/brayden-merrifield/pen/XWXvXee) to view how it looks.

Comment: Hey, This is it. I have made few modifications to get what I wanted. Thanks.